# tcmalloc: allocation failed -- what is npages?

Tags: c++, memory, tcmalloc

I've recently run across the error message

```
central_freelist.cc:322 tcmalloc: allocation failed 16384
```

Looking at the source code, I see that that tcmalloc is reporting "npages".

How should I interpret this number?  What information does it provide me to help me debug an application?  Is there a way to tell how big a 'page' is, or if npages is an unreasonable value?

Comment: You've probably corrupted some of the memory manager's internal structures, for example by using dangling pointers.

Comment: Not what I asked, but I'm grateful for the observation -- You assertion sounds completely reasonable,  but would you have a convincing link or technical argument to back the statement?